# how to use hash for calling a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser-history

I have a website that working totaly with ajax and I didn't consider page back and forwarding button.

and now I want to make this: that when user click on back button, the previouse ajax reload.

I have a function that all forms ajax run from.

```
function formajax(url,result,other)
{
    post method...
}
```

and recently I added this code end of the function.

```
window.location.hash = url;
```

how can I use this hash to run this url again in back button?

I try:

```
$(function(){
    if(window.location.hash)
    {
         formajax(window.location.hash);
    }
});
```

but it is not working in windows back. just working in reload...

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your functionality in a setInterval() function like so:

```
setInterval(function{
     formajax(window.location.hash);
}, 1000);
```

*Also, you might want to store the last hash in a variable and check against that to make sure that the function is only run on hash changes.